# does function in sapply execute only the last one command?

Tags: r, function, sapply

I wrote the following code:

```
sapply(1:2, function(x) 
  sapply(2:3, function(y) {
    x+y
    x*y }
  ))
```

I hope to get

3(1+2), 2(1*2), 4(1+3), 3(1*3)

4(2+2), 4(2*2), 5(2+3), 6(2*3)

but R only returns the results of the 2nd command(x*y)

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    4
[2,]    3    6
```

Then I tried the following code:

```
sapply(4:5, function(x) {
  x+1
  x*2 }
)
```

and R returns

```
[1]  8 10
```

Does function in sapply execute only the last command?

How could I rewrite the code to get what I need?

Comment: If there is no `return(...)` in a function, the function returns the value of the last calculated expression.

Comment: Thank you to remind me this rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do a concatenation with `c`

```
sapply(1:2, function(x) 
   sapply(2:3, function(y) {

    c(x+y,
        x*y) }
   ))
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    3    4
#[2,]    2    4
#[3,]    4    5
#[4,]    3    6
```

or if the output types are different, then place in a `list` or a `data.frame`

Comment: If I place the output in data.frame like data.frame(Add=x+y, Mult=x*y), R doesn't show the column names Add and Mult, is there any way to modify it or I could just assign the data.frame to a variable and change the  column names?

Comment: @ycc You can try `do.call(rbind, lapply(1:2, function(x) do.call(rbind, lapply(2:3, function(y) data.frame(Add = x+y, Mult = x*y)))))`